# Add horizontal axis per series in excel

Tags: excel

How frustrating is Excel.. working on this for half an hour now.

I simply try to make a frequency plot of two groups, with different colours. On the x-axis I would like to display the subject.ids per bar.

However, if I select a different range for the horizontal x axis per series (series 1 = blue, series 2 = orange) with the subject id, it changes the x-axis in the other series to the same. What in hell am i doing wrong?
 [image]

```
3007    1
23121   1
3009    1
3005    1
3011    2
23171   2
3207    2
3102    3
3207    6
13302   7
2411    11
23191   11
3008    11
3106    12

110031  1
110031  1
110030  1
110017  1
110014  1
110008  1
110004  1
110007  2
110035  4
110020  4
110003  4
110036  10
110019  11
110015  21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot put 2 series onto the x axis.
You have 2 alternate ways to solve your problem:

1. Concatenate each positional pair into a new column and use this as the x-axis label series. It will look like this:
   [image: Concatenate x-axis]
2. You could use data labels for each series. However, this will add the data to the columns themselves and not the axis (you could put it at the base of the column). To do so, you will need to right click on the graph, select 'Add Data Labels'. By default it adds the value as the label, but you can select the labels, right click to format the data labels and use the 'values from cells' option. Once you do this and play around with the orientation and location of the labels, it will look like this:
   [image]

For simplicity, I'd go with the first method

Adding a 3rd option; simply put the columns for the axis labels beside each other and when selecting the Data for the Axis Labels, just select both columns instead of the usual 1. It will look like this:
[image: 2column_xaxis]

Comment: That's actually really good, impressed. I should have come up with the second... :P I was thinking to split the two series (by select a combo chart) and add a secondary axis. Then you can remove the secondary vertical and add the secondary horizontal, but representation is not nearly as good as your solution.!!! You can't have the 2 series on the _same x-axis_. But you can have a secondary.

Comment: Yea, I was thinking of a similar idea. For eg, if you have the 2 axis columns beside each other, you don't even need to concatenate, and can have both labels within the x-axis without concatenating; you just need to select both the columns when selecting the data for the axis. I'm going to add that to the answer above

Comment: @godspeed23.carl thanks a alot. Like others already mentioned, its a great work around